# Javascript working locally but not on webserver. (Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem for which I have been searching the net for hours, but I can't find the solution.
I wrote a webpage with JQuery included. It runs file locally (as a file), but on the webserver, it keeps giving me an error: 'Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined'. When I debug the html when loaded in chrome locally I can see the content of the referenced .js files. However when I debug the same files when the page runs on the webserver I can see the .js files in the debugger, but they appear all empty, ergo no content. The paths to the files is correct as the debugger gives no errors on the files not found.

Please, help??? Here is my code:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html><head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="web.css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery/jquery.treetable.css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery/jquery.treetable.theme.default.css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery/jquery-ui.css"/>
 </head>
 <body>
 <Template>HEADER</Template>
 <table id="statustable"><tr><th><div><span>Type</span></div></th><th><div><span>Nummer</span></div></th><th><div><span>Beschrijving</span></div></th><th><div><span>Status</span></div></th><th><div><span>SubStatus</span></div></th><th><div><span>Prod. soort</span></div></th><th><div><span>Plaat Best.</span></div></th><th><div><span>Rail spuiter</span></div></th><th><div><span>Hout</span></div></th><th><div><span>Aluminium</span></div></th><th><div><span>Staal</span></div></th><th><div><span>Rubberen</span></div></th><th><div><span>Assemblage</span></div></th><th><div><span>Werknemer</span></div></th></tr><tr data-tt-id="1"><td style="background-color:lightblue;">Project</td><td>BV19073</td><td>Engel</td><td>Order</td><td>Gereed</td></tr><tr data-tt-id="1.1" data-tt-parent-id="1"><td style="background-color:lightblue;">Order</td><td>1900198</td><td>Engel</td><td>Order</td><td>Productie_gereed</td><td style="background-color:green;">PRODUCTIE</td><td style="background-color:green;">Gereed</td><td style="background-color:Red;">Geen</td></tr><tr data-tt-id="1.1.1" data-tt-parent-id="1.1"><td style="background-color:lightblue;">Samenstelling</td><td>01.</td><td>Wand A P90 46/47 dB</td><td>Gereed</td></tr><tr data-tt-id="1.1.1.1" data-tt-parent-id="1.1.1"><td style="background-color:lightblue;">Onderdeel</td><td>01.01.</td><td>Wall Stanchion Telescopic (WST)</td><td>Gereed</td></tr><tr data-tt-id="1.1.1.2" data-tt-parent-id="1.1.1"><td style="background-color:lightblue;">Onderdeel</td><td>01.02.</td><td>Wall Stanchion Standard (WSS)</td><td>Gereed</td></tr><tr data-tt-id="1.1.1.3" data-tt-parent-id="1.1.1"><td style="background-color:lightblue;">Onderdeel</td><td>01.03.</td><td>Standard Panel (SP)</td><td>Gereed</td></tr><tr data-tt-id="1.1.1.4" data-tt-parent-id="1.1.1"><td style="background-color:lightblue;">Onderdeel</td><td>01.04.</td><td>Telescopic Panel (TP)</td><td>Gereed</td></tr><tr data-tt-id="1.1.1.5" data-tt-parent-id="1.1.1"><td style="background-color:lightblue;">Onderdeel</td><td>01.05.</td><td>extra platen ivm min. best.</td><td>Gereed</td></tr><tr data-tt-id="1.1.1.6" data-tt-parent-id="1.1.1"><td style="background-color:lightblue;">Onderdeel</td><td>01.06.</td><td>Uren per wand.</td><td>Gereed</td></tr></table><table id="formtable"><tr><td><button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='##BASEURL##/list/orderpost'">Vernieuwen</button></td></tr></table><Template>FOOTER</Template>
 <script src="jquery/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <script src="jquery/jquery.treetable.js"></script>
 <script src="jquery/test.js"></script>
 <script>(function($){$("#statustable").treetable({ expandable: true })})(jQuery);</script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: *"but they appear all empty, ergo no content"* That's what you need to debug, it would appear that either A) The files on the web server are empty, or B) Your web server isn't serving them correctly.

Comment: A couple of side notes (not related to the question): 1. Your HTML is not valid XHTML (XML), so you should remove the XML declaration on the first line. Writing XHTML correctly is **hard**. Ensuring that your web server is serving it correctly is awkward. I strongly recommend writing HTML5 instead. 2. Use a doctype. The HTML5 doctype is `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Comment: Check your browser devtools and look at the network requests for the JS files.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, The files on the server are not empty, as when I use the same files when I open the file locally (as a file) in chrome. The webserver is a local server also accessible as a fileserver, which is why I can use the same files locally and via the webserver.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, I know about the XML, however the page is generated with a Delphi script which generates XML by default. The Delphiscript is used to grab data from the database of our ERP and add that to the page generated.

Comment: @Don't Panic, I used the devtools from Chrome already to debug the page. That is how I found out that the content of the java scripts was not loaded, while the path to the files was correct (no errors).

Comment: So what did it show - 200/OK but empty files? 404s? 500? If you view the JS URL in your browser do you see content or an error?  What do your web server logs show? C'mon, debug it! ;-)

Comment: @Don't Panic. Devtools does not show any errors on loading the files. The URL shows no content of the java files. I have no excess to the webserver logs as the webserver is part of the ERP software. However, the problem is already solved by using CDNs. Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: The problem is not solved, you worked around it.  Maybe that's enough right now, but if you don't understand and fix the issue it is likely to bite you somehow in future.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **jQuery** CDNs

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html><head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="web.css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-treetable@3.2.0-1/css/jquery.treetable.css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-treetable@3.2.0-1/css/jquery.treetable.theme.default.css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
 </head>
 <body>
 <Template>HEADER</Template>
 <table id="statustable"><tr><th><div><span>Type</span></div></th><th><div><span>Nummer</span></div></th><th><div><span>Beschrijving</span></div></th><th><div><span>Status</span></div></th><th><div><span>SubStatus</span></div></th><th><div><span>Prod. soort</span></div></th><th><div><span>Plaat Best.</span></div></th><th><div><span>Rail spuiter</span></div></th><th><div><span>Hout</span></div></th><th><div><span>Aluminium</span></div></th><th><div><span>Staal</span></div></th><th><div><span>Rubberen</span></div></th><th><div><span>Assemblage</span></div></th><th><div><span>Werknemer</span></div></th></tr><tr data-tt-id="1"><td style="background-color:lightblue;">Project</td><td>BV19073</td><td>Engel</td><td>Order</td><td>Gereed</td></tr><tr data-tt-id="1.1" data-tt-parent-id="1"><td style="background-color:lightblue;">Order</td><td>1900198</td><td>Engel</td><td>Order</td><td>Productie_gereed</td><td style="background-color:green;">PRODUCTIE</td><td style="background-color:green;">Gereed</td><td style="background-color:Red;">Geen</td></tr><tr data-tt-id="1.1.1" data-tt-parent-id="1.1"><td style="background-color:lightblue;">Samenstelling</td><td>01.</td><td>Wand A P90 46/47 dB</td><td>Gereed</td></tr><tr data-tt-id="1.1.1.1" data-tt-parent-id="1.1.1"><td style="background-color:lightblue;">Onderdeel</td><td>01.01.</td><td>Wall Stanchion Telescopic (WST)</td><td>Gereed</td></tr><tr data-tt-id="1.1.1.2" data-tt-parent-id="1.1.1"><td style="background-color:lightblue;">Onderdeel</td><td>01.02.</td><td>Wall Stanchion Standard (WSS)</td><td>Gereed</td></tr><tr data-tt-id="1.1.1.3" data-tt-parent-id="1.1.1"><td style="background-color:lightblue;">Onderdeel</td><td>01.03.</td><td>Standard Panel (SP)</td><td>Gereed</td></tr><tr data-tt-id="1.1.1.4" data-tt-parent-id="1.1.1"><td style="background-color:lightblue;">Onderdeel</td><td>01.04.</td><td>Telescopic Panel (TP)</td><td>Gereed</td></tr><tr data-tt-id="1.1.1.5" data-tt-parent-id="1.1.1"><td style="background-color:lightblue;">Onderdeel</td><td>01.05.</td><td>extra platen ivm min. best.</td><td>Gereed</td></tr><tr data-tt-id="1.1.1.6" data-tt-parent-id="1.1.1"><td style="background-color:lightblue;">Onderdeel</td><td>01.06.</td><td>Uren per wand.</td><td>Gereed</td></tr></table><table id="formtable"><tr><td><button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='##BASEURL##/list/orderpost'">Vernieuwen</button></td></tr></table><Template>FOOTER</Template>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-treetable@3.2.0-1/jquery.treetable.min.js"></script>
 <script src="jquery/test.js"></script>
 <script>(function($){$("#statustable").treetable({ expandable: true })})(jQuery);</script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, although it takes a lot longer to load the page and somehow the stylesheets don't work any more. Still I'm a bit further now and I can try to find the rest myself. Thanks a lot. Okay found the problem with the stylesheets aswell (wrong path|). All is working fine now thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this file Worked it**

> New Js file add or old Js file remove

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This might actually work as well. However, I already implemented the solution from Jay. which is pretty much the same except that all the  java files are grabbed with CDNs. Thanks again.